# Swift: Using Core data to update one row [ indexPath.row ]

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In my Application using core data to save user history, everything is working as expected, I need to update one row value when the user hit custom button.

```
    // reverse file lock status
@IBAction func reverseLockStatus(sender: AnyObject) {

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath!

    if let superview = sender.superview {
        if let cell = superview!.superview as? CustomTableViewCell {
            indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        }
    }




    //1
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("DownloadHistory",
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DownloadHistory")

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", indexPath.row)


    //3
    record.setValue(false, forKey: "isLocked")

    try! managedContext.save()


    //self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

I build up the fetchRequest to get the wanted row, I don't know how to set/save the updated value to False.

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://softwarejuancarlos.com/2015/12/19/swift-2-examples-9-core-data-create-get-update-and-remove-entities/

Answer (score 0):

You can cast object to NSManagedObject child, in your case is 'DownloadHistory', and use property directly.

```
let record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! DownloadHistory

record.isLocked = false
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.